# Creating raw OpenGL texture data (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glew

So basically I'm trying to create my own texture in code. Specifically I'm writing a ray tracer and want to display the result as a texture rendered to a quad on the screen.

But how does one exactly go about creating your own texture and then applying it to the screen quad? I've been at this for days without any particular results. What I get now is a quad onto the screen but the texture is one color for the entire quad. But in my example here I want it to be 1/3 white and 2/3 black and this is how I imagine it to be done.

I want to keep OpenGL as barebone as possible. I'm not planning on expanding it so any answer that contains an "ugly hack" is totally fine for as long as it works. I'm using Glew, GLFW and GLM.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
GLFWwindow* window;

//Create a texture that should be 1 third black and 2 thirds white?
unsigned char texdata[SCREEN_HEIGHT * SCREEN_WIDTH * 3];
for(int i=0; i<SCREEN_HEIGHT * SCREEN_WIDTH * 3; i++)
{
    if(i < SCREEN_HEIGHT * SCREEN_WIDTH)
        texdata[i] = 255;
    else
        texdata[i] = 0;
}
//cam.createTexture(texdata);

initOpenGL(window);

GLuint t = 0;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Required for glBuildMipmap() to work (!)
glGenTextures( 1, &t );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t);
// Set parameters to determine how the texture is resized
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_LINEAR );
// Set parameters to determine how the texture wraps at edges
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S , GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T , GL_REPEAT );
// Read the texture data from file and upload it to the GPU
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0,
             GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texdata);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLuint programID = LoadShaders("vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl");
glUseProgram(programID);
// Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders

Objects screenquad;
screenquad.createBox(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

do{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    screenquad.render();
    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
       glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );
```

GLSL shader code:

```
#version 450

in vec2 Texcoord;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main(){
    outColor = texture(tex, Texcoord);
}
```

And the vertex shader:

```
#version 450
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 Normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 Texcoord;

void main(){
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

EDIT: 
Internals of creating the screenquad:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ddavidtran/Fishualization/master/OpenGL/Objects.cpp

Comment: Are you sure that your texture coordinates are correct?  A completely white texture could result from all texture coordinates being [0,0].

Comment: The source of `screenquad` internals would be helpful. Also, you don't bind the texture to the shader program, which is probably the reason of error.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but the code I used for creating the screen quad I have used before in a project and it generates texture coordinates as you would except. I have tried looking into if the texture coordinates are wrong but my knowledge of OpenGL is simply not enough to come to any conclusion....

Comment: I edited and included the link to the cpp where I created the screenquad. It's a file from my previous project which works good there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tex` uniform is not set in the code. It could be done roughly like this:

```
GLint texUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "tex");
glUniform1i(texUniformLocation, 0);
```

Here, `0` in [`glUniform1i`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) is the current active [*texture image unit*](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_image_units), which is `GL_TEXTURE0` by default. You can change it via [glActiveTexture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml).

However, as BDL noticed, `0` is actually the default value, so you may skip this part.

Another problem is that your texture coordinates are wrong. As seen in the [file you linked](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ddavidtran/Fishualization/master/OpenGL/Objects.cpp), in function `Objects::createBox`, the vertex data is

```
const GLfloat vertex_array_data[] = {
    -xsize, -ysize, -zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Vertex 0
    xsize, -ysize, -zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Vertex 1
    -xsize, ysize, -zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // Vertex 2
    xsize, ysize, -zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // Vertex 3
    -xsize, -ysize, zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Vertex 0
    xsize, -ysize, zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Vertex 1
    -xsize, ysize, zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // Vertex 2
    xsize, ysize, zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f  // Vertex 3
};
```

The last two floats in each row are the texture coordinates. As you can see, all of them are 0. *The normals are also strange, but you don't use them anyway.*

I have no idea what texture coordinates for a box you would like, but for a quad I'd do something like this:

```
const GLfloat vertex_array_data[] = {
    -xsize, -ysize, -zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Vertex 0
    xsize, -ysize, -zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Vertex 1
    -xsize, ysize, -zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // Vertex 2
    xsize, ysize, -zsize, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // Vertex 3
};
```

Comment: Completely correct that one should always set the texture unit. But note, that 0 is the default value for the sampler and thus setting it should not 
be required.

Comment: @BDL True, didn't think of the default value, thank you.

Comment: Ok I tried adding your code but nothing happens. The thing is that I still have some connection between the "texture" I'm creating and the output. If I change a value in it it will change the color of what I see, but not in the way one would expect, and only in gray values.

Comment: @JakobBertlin Yes, I was wrong, it shouldn't have changed anything. I've updated the answer with another problem.

Comment: So If I would want to hard code this I could just set the texture coordinates in the positions I want when createBox() is called? 

(0,0) in bottom left, (1,1) in top right and so on....?

Comment: @JakobBertlin Yes, this should work. Having all texture coordinates set to 0 is meaningless anyway - the object will always have the same color. You may also consider implementing a `createQuad(float xsize, float ysize)` function, since you don't actually need a full box in your case.

Comment: Okay thanks! My texture coordinates work good now, I have confirmed with a texture/image loader and it maps the image perfectly to the screen/quad. 

However I will create a new question here on stack overflow as I still don't know how to create my own texture from scratch. Feel free to help me there again if you know how!